# Ruby cannot find nokogiri/nokogiri

Tags: ruby, rubygems, rvm, nokogiri

I'm using RVM and previously RBENV on OSX. I have my gems installed relative to my project path in `./gems`

I am using the `aws-sdk` and attempting to use the s3 client results in a `LoadError` from `nokogiri/nokogiri`. Specifically the error is:

```
/gems/ruby/1.9.1/gems/backports-2.6.7/lib/backports/tools.rb:314:in `require': cannot load such file -- nokogiri/nokogiri (LoadError)
```

There has been a few discussions around the internet about this, but not a whole lot of answers. The odd thing is that this works, in its current configuration on Heroku.

I don't know if it helps, but I previously had an issue with `bcrypt-ruby`, where it was not finding `bcrypt_ext` in the same manner, `LoadError, cannot find such file`. The only resolution to that was seemingly to go into the gem folder and manually make install the file.

Answer (score 0):

after changing to project directory run:

```
GEM_PATH=$GEM_PATH:$PWD/.gems
```

Comment: That didn't seem to help, regardless of running that in terminal it still complains about nokogiri. I've found that if I install the gems to the system folder via bundle install --system that it works, but once I change back to a relative gem directory it breaks again.

Comment: it is important to understand how your tools work, RVM will use gemsets and you need to run `rvm use ruby[@gemset]` to get access to the gems, if you use `bundler` to install gems then you need to also run them using `bundle exec` like `bundle exec rake`.